# What are the p:ajax events available for slider component in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.3.1 in that I want to know what are the p:ajax events available for the **slider** component in primefaces.

Answer (score 4):

From PF 3.3 manual:

> Slider provides one ajax behavior event called *slideEnd* that is fired
>   when the slide completes.

That's all!